# Blockchain REST endpoint not accessible

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric

I have a docker-compose file as [here](https://pastebin.com/RP3qnAjQ). I can connect to 7051 and register my chaincode client, but when I try to connect to localhost:7050, I get an error which when tested with curl is as follows :

```
curl -v localhost:7050
* STATE: INIT => CONNECT handle 0x80059aa8; line 1410 (connection #-5000)
* Rebuilt URL to: localhost:7050/
* Added connection 0. The cache now contains 1 members
* STATE: CONNECT => WAITRESOLVE handle 0x80059aa8; line 1446 (connection #0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* STATE: WAITRESOLVE => WAITCONNECT handle 0x80059aa8; line 1527 (connection #0)
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 7050 (#0)
* STATE: WAITCONNECT => SENDPROTOCONNECT handle 0x80059aa8; line 1579 (connection #0)

* Marked for [keep alive]: HTTP default
* STATE: SENDPROTOCONNECT => DO handle 0x80059aa8; line 1597 (connection #0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:7050
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.1
> Accept: */*
>
* STATE: DO => DO_DONE handle 0x80059aa8; line 1676 (connection #0)
* STATE: DO_DONE => WAITPERFORM handle 0x80059aa8; line 1801 (connection #0)
* STATE: WAITPERFORM => PERFORM handle 0x80059aa8; line 1811 (connection #0)
* Recv failure: Software caused connection abort
* Marked for [closure]: Transfer returned error
* multi_done
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
* The cache now contains 0 members
* Expire cleared
curl: (56) Recv failure: Software caused connection abort
```

I have enabled port-forwarding for my docker toolbox vm for all ports in the docker compose file : 7050, 7051, 7053.

I run docker from windows using the docker toolbox.

My docker setup is as follows:

- Docker version 1.12.2, build bb80604
- docker-compose version 1.8.1,
  build 004ddae

Can someone help me troubleshoot my hyperledger REST API problem ?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hypeledger Fabric version 1.0.0 doesn't have REST API, the communication is done with gRPC. To interact the Hyperledger Fabric you need to leverage one of provided SDKs, currently available:

1. [Java SDK](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java)
2. [Node SDK](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node)
3. [Go SDK](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go)
4. [Python SDK](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-py)

To test basic functionality you might also consider using `peer cli` tool which provide you with capabilities to work against endorsing peer to create a new channel, join peer to the channel, install/instantiate of chaincode and of course invoke and query chaincode. You can find more information in [documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: Looks like there was a json REST api until v0.6 (https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/v0.6/core/rest/rest_api.json). Is there any reason why this was discontinued ?